# $ifNull inside the range operator in mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation, atlas

I am trying to get all the products that have the price.v2 < maxPrice if price.v2 is not null, or price.v1 < maxPrice if price.v2 is null

I tried this code here but it says "compound.must[0].range.path.value" must be a string"

```
 const products = await Product.aggregate([
{
  $search: {
    index: "ProductSearchIndex",
    compound: {
      must: [
        {
    range: {
      path: {
        value: {
          $ifNull: ["$price.v2", "$price.v1"],
        },
      },
      lte: filters.maxPrice,
    },
  }
      ],
    },
  },
},
{
  $project: {
    score: { $meta: "searchScore" },
    _id: 0,
    id: "$_id",
  },
},
]);
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: Please add some sample documents, along with the expected output.